# get elements by class name and store element in variable

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to do the following:

```
function() {
 var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('class');
 var length = elements.length;
 for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  var element = elements[i];
  element.addEventListener('input', function() { return handleInputEvent(element); }, false);
 }
}
function handleInputEvent(element) {
 var value = element.value; // empty string
}
```

but when I try to get the element's value, it keeps coming back as an empty string even though I'm typing in a number or letter. Any ideas?

html is a bunch of inputs

```
<input type='text' class='class'/>
<input type='text' class='class'/>
<input type='text' class='class'/>
```

Comment: can you include the html?

Comment: @depperm sure one sec

Comment: Why do you have a `function()` without an identifier/name? I don't think it'll run without being called.

Comment: @jlam55555 thats not the point, theres a name on the function in my code

Comment: Do you call that function though? Just making sure.

Comment: @jlam55555 yes, how else would I get an empty string when I'm debugging?

Comment: Oh. Your `handleInputElement()` function is not returning anything.

Comment: The reference to *element* is being held in a closure, there are many, many answers for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're redefining `element` every time you go through the loop. When you use element in each event function, it means that the function will be executed using the value of element at the time of function execution, so `element` will always refer to the last value `element`, which would be the last element in `elements`. So if the last element in `elements` has a value of `''`, then the output will be `''`.

But not only that, you don't actually return the `element.value`, you simply leave it as a local variable inside the handling function. You should replace

```
var value = element.value;
```

With

```
return element.value;
```

Or

```
console.log(element.value);
```

Comment: nailed it, good catch. I just tested and that seems to be happening.

Comment: But `element` is passed as an argument in `handleInputElements()`; it's not the global variable. It has local scope - it will not be affected by the `elements[]` array. This is wrong.

Comment: I don't need to return a value, I do other stuff in the function, but that's outside the scope of the question

Comment: @jlam55555 I know I only covered part of the problem, I edited after reading your comment.

Comment: @AbdulAhmad The not returning anything is causing the empty string -- the empty string is because there *is no value* returned! It **totally** is in the scope of your question.

Comment: and @Tobsta that edit covers it now

Comment: @jlam55555 what are you talking about. I don't need to return a value because I use it in other operations inside the function and then update an html element with the result.

Comment: @AbdulAhmad You didn't show that in your code though.

Comment: @jlam55555 I told you its outside the scope of the question. now please stop bugging me

Comment: @AbdulAhmad Ah ok, that was just unclear. It looked as if that was one of the problems.